# Одновременное считывание и склеивание нескольких текстовых файлов

Tags: c#

Есть значит к примеру 3 текстовых файла. В каждом энное количество строк. К примеру строки все одинаковые (запятая как новая строка) 1,2,3,4,5
должно быть так(эти числа в каждом из текстовых файлов)

```
111
112
113
114
115
121
122
123
124
125
...
555
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно по сути декартово произведение последовательностей. Это можно сделать, например, такой рекурсией:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Cartesian<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    var firstSeq = sequences.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstSeq == null)
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        yield break;
    }
    foreach (var val in firstSeq)
    {
        foreach (var subseq in Cartesian(sequences.Skip(1)))
            yield return new[] { val }.Concat(subseq);
    }
}
```

Теперь применяем:

```
static void Main()
{
    var first = File.ReadLines(firstpath);
    var second = File.ReadLines(secondpath);
    var third = File.ReadLines(thirdpath);

    var combinations = Cartesian(new[] { first, second, third });
    var concatenated = combinations.Select(seq => string.Concat(seq));

    foreach (var result in concatenated)
        Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

---

Если мы заранее задаём число файлов, всё гораздо проще:

```
foreach (var result in
            from first in File.ReadLines(firstpath)
            from second in File.ReadLines(secondpath)
            from third in File.ReadLines(thirdpath)
            select string.Concat(first, second, third))
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: а как быть, если я хочу пропустить Skip(100); первые 100 строк от первого док. ?

Comment: @komra23: Тогда вы просто вместо `File.ReadLines(firstpath)` пишете `File.ReadLines(firstpath).Skip(100)`.

Comment: File.ReadLines(firstpath).Skip(100) а если я хочу дважди пропустить и один раз взять?
словами это так: File.ReadLines(firstpath).Skip(100)||Skip(100).Take(100)

Comment: @komra23: `File.ReadLlines(...).Skip(200).Take(100)`?

Comment: То есть просто через точку можно до бесконечности продолжать что ли ?

Comment: @komra23: А то!

Comment: в принципе все норма, но вот кошмар новый приснился, дело в том что Take можно использовать только один раз, а мне надо множество раз

Comment: @komra23: То есть, вам нужно читать несколько range'ей? Допустим, 100-100, 500-599, 800-899?

Comment: ДА.............

Comment: @komra23: Это более серьёзный вопрос. Его стоит задать отдельно, в двух словах я вам такое не распишу.

Comment: Можете тогда написать название темы, и вопрос , я создам тему прямо щяс:)
вам больше репутации будет

Comment: @komra23: Ну, хм, вам же лучше знать, что вам нужно. Например, «выбрать из `IEnumerable<T>` элементы из нескольких диапазонов», что-то такое.

Comment: http://goo.gl/yi5XGA

Comment: @komra23: Ага, написал ответ.