# Слить несколько тхт с разными рангами

Tags: c#

Дана последовательность (`IEnumerable<T>`), нужно получить из неё другую последовательность, содержащую несколько range'ей.

Допустим, элементы 100-199, 500-599, 800-899.

Я пробовал выразить это через `.Skip` и `Take`, но таким образом выходит получить лишь один диапазон, т. к. `Take` «забывает» остаток последовательности.

Comment: Вообще ничего непонятно.

Comment: А что вам мешает использовать .Take(5)  несколько раз?

Comment: @Mirdin, подозреваю, что имелось ввиду взять _следующие_ 5, и с одним `Take(5)` это действительно проблематично

Comment: Стоит как минимум добавить ссылку на прошлый вопрос, и перенести **всю информацию** о новом вопросе из комментариев

Comment: в дополнение к коментарию @Grundy было бы не плохо привести пример исходных данных и необходимый результат

Comment: @Bald, исходные данные, я так понимаю, такие же как и в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548520/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @Grundy имеете в виду, что ТС знает Take(), но не знает Skip() ;))))))

Comment: @Mirdin
этот вопрос был задан для другого человека, он знает что я ему задал этот вопрос

Comment: @komra23, это не отменяет ужасного качества вопроса, и тот факт, что  вопросы тут задаются для всех

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня вышло как-то так:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static RangeListEnumerable<T> TakeRanges<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> seq, int from, int howmuch)
    {
        return new RangeListEnumerable<T>(seq, from, howmuch);
    }
}

class RangeListEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> seq;
    SortedList<int, int> ranges;

    public RangeListEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> seq, int from, int howmuch)
    {
        CheckRange(null, from, howmuch);
        this.seq = seq;
        this.ranges = new SortedList<int, int>() { [from] = howmuch };
    }

    RangeListEnumerable(
        IEnumerable<T> seq, SortedList<int, int> ranges, int from, int howmuch)
    {
        CheckRange(ranges, from, howmuch);
        this.seq = seq;
        this.ranges = new SortedList<int, int>(ranges) { [from] = howmuch };
    }

    static void CheckRange(SortedList<int, int> ranges, int from, int howmuch)
    {
        if (from < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("from must be non-negative");
        if (howmuch < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("howmuch must be non-negative");
        if (ranges == null)
            return;
        var to = from + howmuch;
        foreach (var kvp in ranges)
        {
            if (kvp.Key < to && kvp.Key + kvp.Value > from)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"intersecting ranges [{kvp.Key}, {kvp.Key + kvp.Value}) " +
                    $"and [{from}, {to})");
            }
        }
    }

    public RangeListEnumerable<T> AndRange(int from, int howmuch)
    {
        return new RangeListEnumerable<T>(seq, ranges, from, howmuch);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int currIdx = 0;
        using (var e = seq.GetEnumerator())
        {
            foreach (var range in ranges)
            {
                var start = range.Key;
                var end = range.Key + range.Value;
                // skip
                while (currIdx < start)
                {
                    if (!e.MoveNext())
                        yield break;
                    currIdx++;
                }
                // take
                while (currIdx < end)
                {
                    if (!e.MoveNext())
                        yield break;
                    currIdx++;
                    yield return e.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Проверка:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 75);
    var y = x.TakeRanges(10, 10).AndRange(30, 10).AndRange(70, 10).AndRange(0, 5);
    foreach (var v in y)
        Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

выдаёт

```
0
1
2
10
11
12
30
31
32
70
71
72
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<int> GetCurrentPage(
    IEnumerable<int> source
  , int page_number = 0
  , int page_size = 5
)
{
    return source.Skip(page_number * page_size).Take(page_size);
}
```